# HTML input value attribute - same input, (apparently) different results

Tags: javascript, html, input

How does value attribute work for the html input tag after an edit via the inputbox?

example:

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="Hello world" />
```

this will show an input box with the text "Hello world". If I edit it inputing a new string into the rendered textbox (not via raw code), and then try to get his value using js like this

```
alert(document.getElementById('test').value)
```

I'll, correctly, get the NEW value. 
But if I inspect the element through chrome developer tools (or firebug or anything you prefer), I'll see the same "Hello world" string as it was in the beginning..

Which of the two is the right one? js value or chrome inspector?

Here's the [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BwnEK/1/) and here's a screenshot[image]

I came up to this while trying to find a solution to this problem: Classic shop situation, I have a table with X inputs tag  , where an user can input the quantity of X items. I need to check if one or more values have changed since the previous value of each input: if the comparison between OLD and NEW val returns that the valuehas changed, I need to update the order. Otherwise there's no need to save/update.

I thought I could use attr. "value" to store the "old" value of the input, but probably was not the best choice..

Can anyone explain this behaviour? It's only a "refresh" problem or is there something else behind?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are right, they just show different things.

The DOM `value` **property** gives you the **current** value.

The HTML `value` **attribute** gives you the **default** value (the same as the DOM `defaultValue` **property**).

The Chrome DOM inspector shows you attribute values in the HTML view. You have to look at the property view to see the property values.

[image: Screen shot of Chrome property view]

Answer (score 6):

You can find information in this [article](http://www.willis-owen.co.uk/2012/04/jquery-changing-form-values-not-affecting-the-dom/).

the value seen in html is the default value the form is loaded with. If you want the DOM also to update then you have to use ele.setAttribute("value",  "new value")

If you want to know if a element is changed, the best is to attach a onchange event to the input elements and mark some flag in the change handler to know if the form changed or not.

Comment: mmm the onchange will fire even if I input the same value in the input box.. Am I right?

Comment: Generally in our implementations, we create a simple class for input box, where we initialize it with some value. The class willbe responsible for rendering the input element, and listen to its events and when it catches the change event, it can check if the value is actually changed as it caches the initialized value. If you think this is complicating your requirements, then you can maintain an array or list of values, map it to the input elements and can perform check based on the value stored in the array. Either way you  will need some js manipulation

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a so-called proprietary attribute to the input; for example "oldval" so that you can later compare it with current value

Comment: You could, but why bother when `defaultValue` comes for free?